# Identify a sprawling plant with deltoid leaves

Tags: identification

Does anyone know what kind of plant this is?

[image]

Comment: We have a site policy of one type of plant in identification questions. Please ask a separate question for the second one. See https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question-and-be-specific-whep for more about this policy

Comment: Also, with [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please [edit] your question to add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like *Tetragonia tetragonoides*

Photo from wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragonia_tetragonoides

[image]

I see a Nasturtium there also.